# Sub-project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a project 'Company 1' and I want to create subproject inside that project like 'Deploy VM', 'Deploy App' etc. so I can put all 'Company 1' related code inside one project. And I can create multiple builds inside the same project.

But I am not seeing the option to create a sub-project. How can I achieve this in Azure DevOps? Do I have to create multiple repositories in the same project or there is another way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what a "subproject" would represent in your vision. Can you explain the scenario you're trying to achieve more clearly?

Comment: Suppose, 'Company 1' has different sets of ARM template and the company does not want to create a separate project for each ARM template. What they want is to create a single project and put all ARM template there. Each ARM template will have separate Build followed by Release pipelines on the same project.

Comment: Then put them in separate repositories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term `Project` in Azure DevOps is a bit misleading.  It would make more sense if it were called "workspace" or something like that.  Each project can contain a very large number of repositories, build/release piplelines, team spaces, area paths, etc.

In fact, my entire organization lives primarily in one Project space with hundreds of repos and build definitions + dozens of separate team spaces.

Creating separate project will fully segregate concerns, so it's not a good idea unless you want true, full separation with no relationships to the others.

In your scenario, I recommend creating separate repositories and build definitions in the same Project space.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `sub-project` in Azure Devops. Why don't you create a branch for your repo? You can pull/push codes for the new branch.

Git branches aren't much more than a small reference that keeps an exact history of commits, so they are very cheap to create. Committing changes to a branch will not affect other branches, and you can share branches with others without having to merge the changes into the main project. Create new branches to isolate changes for a feature or a bug fix from your master branch and other work. You can add some new features in one branch.

You can also build target or multiple branches using Azure Pipelines or TFS. Please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).